# How can i run diferent image of my OS with diferent configurations depending of what im going to do?

Tags: linux, docker

I would like to be able to run a diferent version or images of my OS. The idea is to have one os installed but being able to run deferent versions. Is like if i want  to ply video games i Just select the image or version of my operative systems that have all i need to do that. If I want to work or program i can tun another version that have all i need to do that. the Idea is to be able to access to all files but have diferent desktop and installed softwares.

Like a personalised work space.

Comment: One way to achieve this is to install several operating systems alongside each other and have a common data partition to store files. Another way is to have one host system (where you plan to work most of the time or where you need most 'horsepower'), create virtual machines and install the other operating systems into those virtual machines. You can use VirtualBox to manage the virtual machines.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install your system on partition (or logical volume) #1
2. Repeat the same as many times as many images you want on different partitions
3. Configure a boot manager like GRUB to have interactive menu with your systems, so you can choose them during boot.
4. Create another partition and mount it on every system under /home

You can further create different users for each system if you don't want to allow all images to modify all files.

If you create the same user on every system, it will have access to your /home/user directory.

Your problem might be probably solved in some smarter way, like multi-user configuration, multi-kernel configuration, multi-driver configuration, docker/firejail or virtual machines. It just depends what your problem is.